# PDO Find a needle in a haystack SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am using PDO, and am thrown an error when using the following code:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE 
                                WHERE INSTR(`games`, '{$gameid}') > 0
                                ");
$gameid = $gamedata['id'];
$stmt->execute(array(
                                ':gameid'=>$gameid
                                ));
$players = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Through looking at past answers this is supposed to work, however I am met with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax 
error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 
INSTR(`games`, 'crysis') > 0' at line 2' in C:\xampp\htdocs\gs\gamepage.php:19 Stack 
trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gs\gamepage.php(19): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} 
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gs\gamepage.php on line 19
```

It also appears it's grabbing 'games' as a literal and not the column

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are there two WHEREs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a double `WHERE`:

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE 
                            WHERE
```

You're also doing some funny things with `$gameid`, namely setting the variable *after* substitution, and binding an unused `:gameid` parameter. You also have a SQL injection vulnerability and should really use a parameter to pass `$gameid` instead of creating dynamic SQL.

Comment: Hi @lc. thank you for this, I do have the variable defined before this bit of code and was trying to debug if that could possibly be the answer!  I have a question about SQL injection though, I am grabbing $gamedata['id'] from another PDO statement, is this still vulnerable, if so how?

Comment: Sure, if `$gamedata['id']` could have ever come from user input, directly or indirectly

Comment: The whole $gamedata array is coming from sanitized sources, I do not see how this is vulnerable to SQLi

Comment: Well if you're guaranteed it's all sanitized then you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You have the word games encased in "back quotes" and not "single quotes" like the {$gameid} variable is using.  They are probably making the db engine assume it is a column name instead of text.

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `username` FROM `users`
        WHERE INSTR(`games`, :gameid) > 0;');
```

And you should use `$stmt->bindValue()` or `$stmt->bindParameter()` before executing the query.

This won't work if gameid is an ... INTEGER ! ? ! ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, gameid is not an integer so no worries.

Comment: So, if this was helpful regarding your question, accept this as answer.